# Can't boot Windows 8, can't boot from USB installer

Tags: windows-8, boot, grub

I'm having all sorts of problems with my PC. It's custom-built so I didn't expect to have UEFI/Secure Boot compatibility issues but I think that's what's happening.

I have a Windows 8 Pro installation on C:. I tried installing Ubuntu 14, which did two things:

- choosing Ubuntu in grub2 takes me to a black screen
- **choosing Windows in grub2 takes me to an error screen:**

`0xc000000e: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.`

I then installed Ubuntu 12 over the Ubuntu 14 installation to se if that would resolve my gfx issues.

**Now booting up takes me directly to `grub-rescue`.**

I made a Windows 8 setup USB drive by using the Windows 7 USB Download Tool and the windows 8 ISO, which has worked for me in the past. But trying to boot from that device just *immediately* takes me to grub-rescue again.

**I have tried:**

- [using oscdimg.exe to make the ISO UEFI-bootable](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/is-anyone-else-having-problems-with-uefi-support/a8e39541-941e-498d-9b23-134a9f9ada87)
- several permutations of options in my BIOS
- [burning the ISO with Rufus](https://superuser.com/a/678325/127867) as GPT for UEFI

With Rufus, the USB drive at least takes me to a Windows boot error screen again:

`Your PC needs to be repaired. An unexpected error has occurred (0xc0000225).`

I thought the Windows 8 installation ISO was capable of startup repair, but it just takes me here.

---

**The following are my potentially relevant available BIOS options (GX-Z87X-UD3H):**

- Fast Boot: `Disabled`
- Windows 8 Features: (`Other OS`, `Windows 8`, `Windows 8 WHQL`)
- - If `Windows 8` or `Windows 8 WHQL`:
- - - CSM Support: (`Always`, `Never`)
- Boot Mode Selection: (`UEFI and Legacy`, `Legacy Only`, `UEFI Only`)
- Storage Boot Option Control: (`Disabled`, `UEFI Only`, `Legacy Only`, `Legacy First`, `UEFI First`)
- Secure Boot state: Disabled
- Secure Boot: (`Disabled`, `Enabled`)

I haven't found a permutation of these options that lets me boot the USB drive.

I can also set a custom policy to "query user" for removable media, but that seems to have no effect.