# Please help installing Zorin OS 15.2 on Asus Eee PC 1001PXD running Windows 7 from USB

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios, usb-flash-drive

so the laptop mentioned above is quite old and runs on Windows 7 (32 bit)very poorly. I figured a lite version of Zorin would do the job, as the computer will only be used for leasurely purposes (Netflix, Solitaire, web-browsing).

So I downloaded the USB image from zorinos.com and made a bootable USB drive via balenaEtcher, as recommended in [this tutorial](https://zorinos.com/help/install-zorin-os/). Well, that didn't work at all, even though in BIOS it is set as a primary boot device.

My pendrive doesn't appear in my Windows 10 after flashing with balenaEtcher (neither in Windows 7). I thought it got bricked, but managed to recover the drive.

Did some googling, and there's potentially a couple of problems to be solved:

[On github, I found this thread](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#help-rufus-damaged-my-flash-drive), someone mentions that it maybe caused by the fact that the machine is not running on BIOS legacy version, but UEFI instead, but it doesn't seem to be the case. In System information, BIOS version is called *American Megatrends Inc. 0702* from *2011-04-11*.

Here, on superuser, I found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/602123/cant-boot-from-usb-even-with-bios-set-correctly), where many potential issues are listed, but I don't even know how to start. Do I format my pendrive in NTFS, and flash again via balenaEtcher?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some trial and error, I managed to install the OS.

I flashed the drive with Rufus, and once again *it stopped being recognised on Windows*.

Nevertheless, I carried on to boot from it on the designated machine, and lo and behold, **it worked**. The installation went on, and after a long while there was only a black screen with a curosor, no hard drive activity.

I forced a quit, and after that it started working.

Now there's no sound, but [that's another issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1578777/dummy-sound-on-linux-mint-mate-19-3-32-bit-on-hardware-asus-eee-pc-1001pxd/1578822#1578822).

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be nice. Personally, I recommend Rufus for flashing drives but it really comes down to personal preference, doesn't it?

Anyhow, if it's UEFI, have you disabled secure boot? Older BIOSes don't usually like Linux operating systems, found that out when trying to run archlinux on my laptop.

If it's Legacy BIOS, you might have to force your boot to the EFI file (this is what worked for me). This is usually located in /boot/EFI/zorin32.EFI (or whatever your EFI file may be called).

You might have also tried installing a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit system. Please doublecheck that. The 32bit OSes are usually ending with xxx-i386.iso

Comment: So to all my understanding, it isn't UEFI, but Legacy. And also, like I mentioned, the drive is not visible in my computer after the flash. I'll try Rufus. The system chosen from Zorin is dedicated to 32-bit system.

Comment: All good, best of luck.